# Search using multiple conditions

Tags: search, fix-protocol

I would like to do a search in a FIX log file using multiple conditions/ criteria. For example:

```
Line 1: a=1 b=2 c=3<br> 
Line 2: a=4 b=3 c=2<br>
Line 3: a=2 b=1 c=3<br> 
Line 4: a=1 b=2 c=4<br>
```

I would like to do a search where `a=1` and `c=3` (which will resurn me 2 lines in this example). A the moment how I did this seach is to seach all `a=1`, then copy paste the result to a new pad, then do another search for `c=3`.

Is there a simpler way to do this in one go as you can imagine the more criterias I have the more single search and copy paste I have to make?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you use grep? Try using [VIM](http://www.vim.org/). Then run a search for the a=1 and pipe the output into a search for c=3, or suchlike...